# Website looks OK in IE9, but not in Firefox, IE8 and IE7

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with my site http://www.cyprusproperty-4sale.com/123456789.asp it looks OK in IE9 but not in Firefox, IE8 & IE7. A small gap appears just above the main picture.
Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I tried viewing it in Firefox 10, Opera IE9 and Chrome, and I could see no evident difference. Could you provide some additional information (screenshot, accurate information of what is wrong, ..)

Comment: in firefox 10 between the header CYPRUSPROPERTY-4SALE.COM and the picture there is a small gap. smaller in IE7&8

Answer (score 2):

The W3C validator finds 95 errors and 21 warnings. Most of these are unimportant (for browser interoperability that is), but you may want to look into some of them. Different browsers respond differently to errors!

For instance, `<form>` in a `<table>`, but outside of a `<td>` is a no-no.

And your page thinks it's XHTML, but it it really would have been XHTML, it wouldn't render at all on Firefox, because it is not well-formed XML, and standards compliant browsers would throw an error.